# looping through xml file

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

what i am trying to do is load an xml file and loop through elements of it,  the xml is structured as so :

```
 <root>

<device>    

    <cat>image</cat>    

    <sub_cat>dslr</sub_cat>

    <booked>-1</booked> 

    <pre_book_st>1/1/2013</pre_book_st> 

    <book_len></book_len>   

    <user>R000XXXY</user>   

</device>

 </root>
```

and the actionscript i am using to get to it is :

```
 convertdataRes();

 import flash.display.MovieClip;

 var xmlloaderRes:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
 var xmlreqRes:URLRequest = new URLRequest("resources.xml");
 xmlloaderRes.load(xmlreqRes);
 trace("xml loader res "+ xmlloaderRes);

 xmlloaderRes.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, convertdata);

 function convertdataRes(event:Event=null):void
{



    var xmlinfo:XML = new XML(event.target.data);
    var postedlist:XMLList = xmlinfo.device;

    var totallist:Number = postedlist.length();

    for(var i:int=0 ; i < totallist ; i++)
    {

    trace(i);
    trace("before");
    trace("xmlinfo.device.cat[i] ="+xmlinfo.device.cat[i]);
    trace("after");

    }


}
```

but when i run it i keep getting the error :

```
 TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
     at v0_fla::MainTimeline/convertdataRes()
     at v0_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

i am unsure of what i am to pass with it, its prob a very basic issue i am just totally lost as to what i need to do, thank you

Comment: The problem is that you're calling `convertdataRes();` at the beginning of your code..

Comment: if i put it at the end, after ive the function created, i get : 1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 1.

Comment: The issue is that function needs an `Event` object to run and your not passing it in

Comment: i dont knwo what to pass to it, i just want to run through the for loop and i would grab what i needed from what, what could i pass to it for it to run ?, i tried null but same issues, sorry about this just a beginner, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you've miss-named the handler on the Event.COMPLETE listener. Remove the 'convertdataRes()' call and change the event listener to:

```
xmlloaderRes.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, convertdataRes);
```

That way the COMPLETE event gets passed to your handler, and the function has an event object to refer to.

Comment: tried that there, it ran without any errors but it gave no output of the for loop, dont know where check whats going on now

Comment: OK, well now you need to get the nodes into an XMLList object. You can extract nodes of a certain name with postedList:XMLList = xml.device.cat or, as samrad says, get all children with postedList:XMLList = xml.device.children(); You can then loop through each xml node with: for each (var xmlNode:XML in postedList) {// action on xmlNode }

Answer (score 0):

This will let you loop through every child in `device` and get the value so you don't have to hardcode `cat`

```
import flash.events.Event;

var xml:XML = <root><device><cat>image</cat><sub_cat>dslr</sub_cat><booked>-1</booked>      <pre_book_st>1/1/2013</pre_book_st><book_len></book_len><user>R000XXXY</user></device></root>;

convertData();

function convertData(event:Event=null):void{

var postedlist:XMLList = xml.device.children();
var totallist:Number = postedlist.length();

 for(var i:int=0 ; i < totallist ; i++)
 {
   trace(postedlist[i]);
        /* --traces --
        image
        dslr
        -1
        1/1/2013

        R000XXXY
        */
 }
}
```